# Деепричастие в качестве обстоятельства места

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот

*Все задачи — составление документации, обработка заявок от клиентов, формирование отчётов — выполняются на компьютере. Поэтому работать можно дома, в кафе и **даже находясь за границей***.

Допустимо ли такое употребление деепричастного оборота в качестве члена однородного ряда обстоятельств места?

У Розенталя есть примеры, когда деепричастный оборот выступает в качестве однородного члена с обстоятельством образа действия (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113).

Comment: Прокомментирую не по сути вопроса. Думаю, предложение составлено некорректно. Если немного подробнее определить занятость, это сразу чувствуется: работать можно дома по хозяйству, поваром в кафе и даже находясь за границей. Чувствуете, что чего-то не хватает в конце?

Comment: @grizzly Я дополню свой пример, чтобы было понятнее, что имеется в виду конкретная работа.

Comment: А, удалённая работа. Тогда так не говорят. Лучше: "работать из дому (или из дома)", "работать из кафе".

Comment: @grizzly Вы имеете в виду, что обычно словосочетания «работать дома», «работать в кафе» предполагают, что работа связана с домом (хозяйство, быт) и с кафе (работа официантом или поваром, например), поэтому их значение лучше уточнить?

Comment: Да, и более того. Когда хотят сказать об удалённой работе, то говорят: "работать из кафе". Сказать в этом случае "работать в кафе" просто язык не поворачивается.

Answer (score 3):

**Поэтому работать можно дома, в кафе и даже находясь за границей.**

Всё верно, деепричастный оборот в роли обстоятельства входит в однородный ряд. По структуре оборот немного отличается от других обстоятельств, так как к нему относится частица ***даже*** (присутствует определенная семантическая неоднородность).

Тем не менее такое оформление ряда **правильно**, но **при большом желании** оборот можно представить как присоединительную конструкцию и отделить запятой.

Comment: Не могли бы привести примеры похожих высказываний из Нацкорпуса или других источников? Просто у Розенталя деепричастный оборот входит в однородный ряд обстоятельств образа действия. *Алёша длинно и как-то прищурив глаза посмотрел на Ракитина* (Дост.). *Остановив Власову, он одним дыханием и не ожидая ответов закидал её трескучими и сухими словами* (М. Г.). А у нас обстоятельства места.

Comment: И как вы относитесь к замечанию @grizzly. Наблюдается некоторая грамматическая и смысловая неоднородность. *Поэтому работать можно дома (где?), в кафе (где?) и даже находясь за границей (что делая?)*.

Comment: Какая разница, это всё обстоятельства места, не может же Розенталь приводить все возможные примеры. Он дает образцы решения, чтобы пользователи потом сами решали свои конкретные задачи.  Кстати, "находясь" можно вообще убрать, грамматика от этого не пострадает.

Comment: @Jasmin Уточню. Я не придирался к неоднородности, я говорил о словоупотреблении. В вопросе имелась в виду удалённая работа, а в таком случае не говорят "работал в кафе".

Comment: @Jasmin То есть деепричастный оборот может быть обстоятельством места?

Comment: Вообще деепричастные обороты могут быть разными обстоятельствами, например: Путешествуя по Франции, я встретил знакомого (времени, одновременные действия) Она успокоилась, увидев, что ветер ослабел (причины)   Я глядел во все стороны, ожидая увидеть грозные бастионы (цели). Сидя дома, мир не посмотришь  (условия). В этом случае их можно заменить соответствующими придаточными.  Как обстоятельства места они не выделяются, но близки по значению к обстоятельствам времени (находясь где-то). Это сближение позволяет им вступать в однородные отношения с обстоятельствами места.

Answer (score 2):

Считаю, что предложение построено не совсем правильно. В каждом из перечисленных случаев важно, что работать можно находясь в каком-то месте. Я бы предложил немного перестроить предложение:
**Работать можно находясь дома, в кафе и даже за границей.**

Здесь обособлять "находясь" не нужно по причине тесной связи со сказуемым (образует смысловой центр действия).

Comment: Как вам такой вариант: «Работать можно со своего ноутбука в любом месте: дома, в кафе и даже (находясь) за границей?

Comment: Да, так можно, наверное. В любом случае это лучше первоначального варианта.